# My ProjectEuler implementation is much too slow

Tags: python, algorithm

These is the problem:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>   What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

These is my solution, but it takes a lot of time!

```
x = 0
check = [11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

while True:
    x += 1
    if all(x % j == 0 for j in check):
        print "The NUMBER is", x
        break
    print x
```

How could I improve it? Is the counter the main problem? Or the while?
**EDIT:** I've seen that there are a lot of differente solutions, but what should I do to check every single number from the 1 and without function like LCM?

Comment: Well, `0` is definitely a poor starting point. Incrementing by 1 value isn't going to be fast either. Those are the simple optimizations

Comment: One obvious speedup would be to increment by 20 each loop, instead of only by one.  (The number you're looking for is obviously going to be a multiple of 20.)

Comment: @JohnGordon: Or even obviously a multiple of 2520.

Comment: There is also a faster algorithm using greatest common denominator and the fact that lcm(a,b,c) = lcm( lcm(a,b), c ). Look it up.

Comment: Ok but if I want to check from the number 1 and without use the lcm function?

Comment: I've just  tried incrementing by 20 and it takes again a lot! If I change it with 2520 it takes like 3 seconds.

Comment: I'd tend to say it's 2520 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 2, but it's only empirical, without any scientific value :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my implementation for a C++ program.

Instead of `number++`, I go for `number += 2`, Why? because odd number are never divisible by 2 therefore reducing my search space from `O(n)` to `O(n/2)`. There is one more way to reduce space search, by shifting the code to `number += 20 (limit)`, because we know that a number of multiple 20 will be divisible from numbers 1-20 (call it advanced maths :P).

Next i start checking from `limit` that is `20` because there is more change of failing at `%limit` than at `2, 3, 4, 5 etc. // smaller numbers`. Therefore reducing computational clock cycles by a bit.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ( ) {
    int limit = 20;

    bool found;
    int number = 2; // OR number = limit; 

    do { 
        found = true;
        for ( int i=limit; i<=1 && found; --i ) {
            if ( number%i != 0 ) found = false;
        }

        number += 2; // OR number += limit;
    } while ( !found );

    cout << "Smallest Number Divisible by all from 1 to " << limit << " is: " << number -= 2 /* OR number -= limit; since we added it one more time @the end */ << endl;
}
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Not all even numbers are divisible by 5, 7, 13 or 19, so you should definitely adjust that number.

Comment: we need only check for 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11. Why? Because if a number is divisible by 20, that mean its by 10 and 5 aswell, reducing our search space. There are thousands of methods to reduce our program complexity. @cricket_007

Comment: thats why i recommended number += 20, that way you won't have to deal with numbers with 5, 7, 13 and 19. @cricket_007

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, i've read your code and i have just deleted my "print x" at the end of the loop, and it works great! And of course n += 20

Answer (score -1):

You could probably start from 2520 to save some time. As per the text, no smaller number could meet that criteria. Plus the task of divisible by numbers 1-20, not 11-20.

Comment: 12 and 15 are missing from the list anyways, so code isn't even checking 11-20

Comment: OP has trimmed the number of divisors to make the tests go faster. You don't have to check 1 -- every number is divisible by 1. You don't have to check 2, because every number divisible by any even number (such as 14, 16, 18, and 20, which *are* in the list) is also divisible by 2. You don't have to check 3 because you're checking 18, which is divisible by 3. And so on up to: you don't have to check 10 because you're checking 20. This is why the list starts at 11.

Comment: @kindall You have to check all prime divisors, yes. Therefore 2, 3, 5, and 7 should be in the list

Comment: But the number has to be divisible by 14, and if it's divisible by 14, it's also divisible by 2. So no, 2 does not need to be checked since 14 is being checked.

Comment: *"OP has trimmed the number of divisors to make the tests go faster."*  The OP should take that technique to its logical conclusion, and just compute `2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19` to get the answer.

Comment: @kindall A number divisible by 2 and 7 will be divisible by 14

Comment: Yes, but then you have to test for both 2 and 7, when instead you can test for 14, which is half the work. Which is why he did it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok thanks all for the amazing suggestion! I've found out that in my case the problem was the `print x`, that took too much time to print in the terminal.
And my final solution is:

```
x = 0
check = [11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

for x in xrange(20, 500000000, 20):
    if all(x % j == 0 for j in check):
        print "The NUMBER is", x
        break
```

It's more clean and it jumps from 20 to 40 and so on, with xrange that is faster from what I've read.

Comment: If it divides itself by [2..20] it also divides itself by [2..10], meaning it's a multiple of 2520 (as someone pointed out). If you modify your `xrange` accordingly, you will process 126 times less numbers which should result in heavy speed increase. You could also remove 20 from `check` and place the primes at the beginning.

Comment: Also 18 and 14 could be removed (missed them yesterday).